# Get the highest value, distinct elements from a list using Stream

Tags: java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I have an `ArrayList` with `Bottle` objects. Each Bottle object has a `brand:String`, and a `price:double` field. I am trying to write an expression using Stream API, so not only I end up with a list of unique bottles, but with a list of unique bottles with the highest price - e.g. if the `ArrayList` contains three Bottle objects of the same name, I would like the one with the highest price to make it into the final list.

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: That the final list has only unique Bottle objects but from three Bottle objects named "BottleA", of which each has a corresponding price 10, 20, and 30, I want the Bottle with price 30 to end up in the final list. The expression I have put together though, does not guarantee that - so it could be the Bottle of price 10, or 20 that makes it into the final list.

Comment: how about adding a comparator?

Comment: So apparently, you don’t want “unique bottles” but “bottles with a unique name (or brand)”. The shown expression is not even remotely connected to this task. So why do you try to alter an entirely unrelated code, instead of trying to straight-forwardly address the actual task?

Comment: Hmm, the code posted returns all the Bottle objects with unique name. On top of that, Id like the Bottle objects that make it into the final list, to be of the highest price, as well.

Comment: Your code returns *one* object, not *all* objects, out of the bottles having the *same* name, i.e. equal to `processedGameRef`, which is the opposite of *unique*.

Comment: You are right, I am sorry, I will remove the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here is an example of how you can find unique with highest prices

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ArrayTest {

    public static class Bottle {
        private final String name;
        private final double price;

        public Bottle(final String name, final double price) {
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Bottle{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", price=" + price +
                '}';
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void uniqueBottles() {
        List<Bottle> bottles = List.of(
            new Bottle("bottle1", 1.),
            new Bottle("bottle1", 2.),
            new Bottle("bottle1", 3.),
            new Bottle("bottle2", 3.5),
            new Bottle("bottle2", 1.5)
        );

        var processedBottleList = bottles
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Bottle::getName, Bottle::getPrice, (p, p2) -> p > p2 ? p : p2))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(e -> new Bottle(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(processedBottleList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a map, with brand name as the key and bottle as the value. And then use a merge function in which, if another bottle is found with the same name, it keeps the bottle with the highest price. Then, get hold of the map values at the end. Here's hot it looks in practice.

```
Collection<Bottle> highestPriceBottles = bottles.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Bottle::getBrand, b -> b,
        BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparingDouble(Bottle::getPrice))))
    .values();
```

Answer (score 0):

If it contains more than two properties **Collectors.toMap**  will not work. Better solution would be

- Sort the list of bottle with the highest price
- Filter (use distinct by key)

```
      List<Bottle> processedBottles = bottles.stream()
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Bottle::getPrice).reversed())
                    .filter(distinctByKey(Bottle::getName))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            //print 
            processedBottles.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Distinct by key:

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(
        Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {

    Map<Object, Boolean> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    return t -> seen.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(t), Boolean.TRUE) == null;
}
```